# Self Join of large data set to obtain time interval overlap

Tags: postgresql, self-join

I have a 14 million row table. I am trying  obtain a sort of "edgelist" where I can observe if a scan data is within a delta time from all the other observations. Trying run the query for a 1% sample of the data took an hour. With 5% it took more than 12 hours. A minimal example of the task is:

The original table

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|    ID    |  SCANDATE  | SCANDATE+D | SCANDATE-D |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| A        | 2018/08/03 | 2018/08/05 | 2018/08/01 |
| B        | 2018/08/04 | 2018/08/06 | 2018/08/02 |
| C        | 2018/08/11 | 2018/08/13 | 2018/08/09 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

REsult:

```
+----------+------------+
|    ID1   | ID2        |
+----------+------------+
|   A      |      B     | 
+----------+------------+
```

The code I am using is this one:

```
   CREATE TABLE edgelist_1 AS (SELECT * FROM 
       (SELECT scan_date,  ship_date,  serial_number,scan_date  
            + interval '3' day AS buffup, scan_date - interval '3'     
       day  AS bufflow FROM bag_list_1 ) AS ims
        INNER JOIN  
       ( SELECT
       scan_date as buff,  serial_number as SN FROM  bag_list_1 ) 
       AS X
       ON ims.serial_number<>X.SN
       WHERE ims.bufflow < X.buff AND ims.buffup  > X.buff )
```

This is the Explain output I get:

```
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..4596699470013.62 rows=21994769623450 width=62)
   Workers Planned: 4
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..2397222506668.62 rows=5498692405862 width=62)
         Join Filter: ((bag_list_1.serial_number <> bag_list_1_1.serial_number) AND ((bag_list_1.scan_date - '3 days'::interval day) < bag_list_1_1.scan_date) AND ((bag_list_1.scan_date + '3 days'::interval day) > bag_list_1_1.scan_date))
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on bag_list_1  (cost=0.00..251629.94 rows=3517394 width=27)
         ->  Seq Scan on bag_list_1 bag_list_1_1  (cost=0.00..357151.75 rows=14069575 width=19)
```

What is a more efficient way to achieve this task.